# How to get data displaying in a table <td> in Cypress.io test?

Tags: javascript, html-table, cypress

In a Cypress.io test, while checking for the 'data' displayed in a table after applying the filter, it throws "CypressError: Timed out retrying: Cannot read property 'eq' of undefined". Can someone please advise how to fix the problem in below test? Table HTML image added below.

```
describe('Filter Test', function() {
    it.only('Check if the records are filtered successfully', function() {
        cy.visit('http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/table-search-filter-demo.html')          
        cy.get('button').contains('Filter').click()
        cy.get('input[placeholder="Username"]').type('jacobs')  
        cy.get('table').should(($tr) => {
        const $tds = $tr.find('td') // find all the tds
        expect($tds.cells.eq(0)).to.contain('jacobs')   
        })

    })      

})
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you `console.log($tds)` to see if it has `cells` object inside ?

Comment: @DarknessZX : Yes I could see the table object inside

Comment: @DarknessZX:  Added the console image for reference

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but the `contains()` function is by far the simplest in this case:

```
cy.get('table').contains('td', 'jacobs');
```

This will get the `table` element and assert that it contains a `td` tag with the text `jacobs`.

---

It's worth noting that `contains()` also acts as a selector, and in typical Cypress fashion you can continue chaining off it, like so:

```
cy.get('table').contains('td', 'jacobs').should('be.visible');

cy.get('table').contains('td', 'jacobs').then(elem => {
    // Do something with this specific element...
});

// etc...
```

Comment: Will try that today evening and reply

Comment: @Joshua Wade - Hi Joshua, is there any way dynamically filter non zeros from a td ?

Comment: Hi @Prany, try this: `cy.get('.my-table').get('td').each(elem => {});` - Cypress will loop through each `td` element and run the provided lambda function with the raw Javascript element passed into `elem`. Now, in the curly braces, you can just do this (or similar, note this is untested): `if (parseFloat(elem.textContent) !== 0) {/*element does *not* contain zero*/} else {/*element contains zero*/}`