# Assert any one element in multiple

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

In Cypress, is it possible to assert that any one of a number of elements matches a specific rule?

For example, something like this:

```
cy.get('nav').children().any.should('have.value', 'My value');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than I thought...

```
cy.get('nav').contains('div', 'My value');
```

This will get the nav element and assert that it contains a div tag with the text `My value`.

Thanks to @JoshuaWade for this solution in his answer to [How to get data displaying in a table  in Cypress.io test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51875052/how-to-get-data-displaying-in-a-table-td-in-cypress-io-test)

Comment: This does not work for me. I need to check the value of an element and if I try `cy.get('[data-testid="my-input"]').should('have.value', 'the value')` it fails if there are multiple ones when the first one does not have the expected value. In other words Cypress doesn't check all the elements, just the first one.